# How do I create a simple table?

Tags: theming, 8

I am working on a module where I need to display content in a table. Though I have created a simple table already, I need to know how to use `theme()`, as the function cannot be called directly.

Basically, What is the equivalent of the following line, which was perfectly fine in Drupal 7?

```
return theme(table,array(header => '$header', rows => '$rows'));
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As reported in [New render element #type 'table'](https://www.drupal.org/node/1876710) and [theme() renamed to _theme() and should not be called directly](https://www.drupal.org/node/2195739), the equivalent of `$table = theme('table', array('header' => $header, 'rows' => $rows))` for Drupal 8 is the following.

```
$form['table'] = [
  '#type' => 'table',
  '#header' => $header,
  '#rows' => $rows,
];
```

(Replace `$form` with the variable containing the rendering array.)

Comment: how is the header supposed to be defined?

Comment: @Matt That didn't change. You define the header as you do with Drupal 7.

Answer (score 5):

Use

```
return [
  '#type' => 'table',
  '#header' => $header,
  '#rows' => $rows,
];
```

Comment: Tried !
No changes in the form

Comment: You should have specified that you are working with a form. For the form the structure is a bit different. Basically you can omit the rows and any child if the element will be a row and any child if that element will be a cell.

Comment: @Clive `'#type' => 'table'` is correct.

Comment: Thanks @kiam haven't seen that element type yet - any idea where the docs are?

Comment: @Clive Some change records show code using #type, but I cannot find any documentation about it.

Comment: @Clive the #type is a form element. See the element namespace. The #theme is a theme function. In case of table they just added a form element that uses the theme function.

Comment: @IvanJaros Actually, #type is for a render element type; it could be a form element or not. In Drupal 7, it was just a form element, but not so in Drupal 8.

Comment: @Clive See the previous comment. I take the difference is that in Drupal 8, you don't have anymore a theme function, which is replaced by a theme template; so, if the rendering is done just in code, without a template file, you implement a render element plugin, and use #type in a render array. See the notes in [Render elements](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core!lib!Drupal!Core!Render!theme.api.php/group/theme_render/8#elements).