# How to change this to D8

Tags: 8

How to change this to Drupal 8 and attach css file to it.

```
$output = theme_table(array('header' => $header, 'rows' => $rows, 'attributes' => array('width' => '100%', 'id' => 'stockapi-table'), 'sticky' => TRUE, 'caption' => t('All available stock quotes.'), 'colgroups' => array(), 'empty' => t('No stock quotes available.'))) . theme("pager");
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I create a simple table?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/184151/how-do-i-create-a-simple-table)

Comment: @leymannx there is also theme("pager") linked and how will I add css to it ?

Comment: @leymannx I want to put it in controller.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This requires two steps:

The first is a render array that contains three elements. The first will be the table, the second the pager, and the third an attached library.

```
$output = [
  'table' => [
    '#type' => 'table',
    '#header' => $header,
    '#rows' => $rows,
    '#empty' => t('No stock quotes available.')
  ],
  'pager' => [
    '#type' => 'pager',
  ],
  '#attached' => [
    'library' => 'mymodule/mylibrary',
  ],
];
```

Next, you need to create the library that was attached in the render array.

#### mymodule.libraries.yml

```
mylibrary:
  css:
    theme:
      css/path_to_my_file.css: {}
```